# Set ASP.NET version to 3.5 in the IIS 6 Default Web site properties (ASP.NET tab)

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

How to set ASP.NET version to 3.5 in the IIS 6 Default Web site properties (ASP.NET tab)? From what I can see was version 2 (even though I have install version .NET 3.5)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify this in IIS. For websites earlier than Framework 4.0 and greater than 2.0 you need to specify version 2.0 in IIS.

However there are configurations in web.config to restrict a website to run or compile under framework version 3.5. Visual Studio by default make these setting in web.config

To be sure here are some parts of the web.config

[image: Compiler version settings]

---

[image: Some Assemblies]

Comment: So, can I assume that what you mean that the ASP.NET version drop-down list, I will only see ASP.NET 2 only. If I have installed .NET 4 Framework, I will be able to see another item - ASP.NET 4 - in the drop-down list?

Comment: FYI, the "3.5" in your picture is not the framework version, per se. It's actually the version of the particular assembly. Those are the "extra assemblies" I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a true "ASP.NET 3.5". "ASP.NET 3.5" is really "ASP.NET 2.0" plus some extra assemblies.

Comment: Do correct me if I have interpret your answer wrongly - what you mean that if I have install .NET 2 and .NET 3.5 framework on the machine, by default, I will only be able to see ASP.NET 2.0 in the 'ASP.NET version' drop down list only, right?

Comment: That is correct. When you install 4.0, then that will be added to the list.